# Insert element in array - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, exception, insert

WHY there is an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception ..Please Clarify :)
I have tried changing the size of the array but still I am unable to create successful program
import java.util.Scanner;

class insert
{

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a[]= new int[5];
    int i;


    for(i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the Element : ");
        a[i]=sc.nextInt();

    }

    System.out.println("Enter the location for insertion : ");
    int loc = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the value for location : " +loc+" is");
    int value = sc.nextInt();

    for(i=a.length-1;i>loc;i--)
    {
        a[i+1]=a[i];
    }
    a[loc-1] = value;
    System.out.println("New Array is : ");

    for (i=0;i<=a.length-1;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

}strong text

Comment: `a[i+1]` throws this exception when `i = a.length-1`.

Comment: Did you try debugging the issue?

Comment: it should be buffer overflow  error.

Comment: There are two lines where this exception can be thrown a[i+1] = a[i] and a[loc-1] = value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part:

```
for(i=a.length-1;i>loc;i--)
    {
        a[i+1]=a[i];
    }
```

On the first iteration, a[i+1] is the same as a[a.length], but **the last element in array is a[a.length-1]**, becausefirst element is a[0] and last one is a[length-1], in total a.length number of elements. So modify your loop accordingly.

One side note, **when you define a size of an array, you cannot change it**. Size is immutable. So you cannot insert an element and try to shift all the elements, because you need to increase the size with 1, which is not possible.
For this scenario, use `ArrayList<Integer>>`. **ArrayList size increases as you add new elements**

Answer (score 0):

It is this for loop throwing the RuntimeException

```
for(i=a.length-1;i>loc;i--) {
    a[i+1]=a[i];
}
```

You are trying to set the value of i + 1 element of the array, which is not existing.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Inserting an element in an array using its Index */


import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int[] b = new int[a.length + 1]; 
        int index = 2;
        int element = 100;
        
        System.out.println("The original array is: "+ Arrays.toString(a));
        
        // In this for loop we iterate the original array from the front
        for (int i = 0; i<index; i++){
            b[i] = a[i];
        }
        // Here we insert the element at the desired index
        b[index] = element;
        
        // In this for loop we start iterating the original array from back.
        for (int i = a.length; i>index; i--){
            b[i] = a[i-1];
            // b[3] = a[2];
        }
        
        System.out.println("The new Array is: " + Arrays.toString(b));
     }
}
```

Output:

The original array is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

The new Array is: [1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 5]